# Issue rendering elements dynamically when data structure I loop through needs an inner loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, conditional-rendering

I am having issues rendering elements dynamically in my React project.

This is my data file **xxx.js**

```
export const valuesText = [
{
    "GB": {
        0: "Responsibility", 
        1: "Hospitality",
        2: "Attention to detail",
        3: "Adaptability",
        4: "Efficiency",
        5: "Passion for Quality"
    },
    "PT": {
        0: "Responsabilidade", 
        1: "Hospitalidade",
        2: "Detalhe e pormenor",
        3: "Adaptabilidade",
        4: "Eficiência",
        5: "Paixão pela Qualidade"
    }
}
]
```

This is my component and the logic to render all the 5 topics depending in the language selected by the user **(GB or PT)**

**Logic to render elements based on data**

```
const textSectionValues = valuesText.map((data) => {
const values = data[props.language]
Object.values(values).map((item, index) => {
    return <div className="hero_section_values_container">
                <h3>{item[index]}</h3>
            </div>
}
)})
```

**Component** adapted so the amount of info is not too noisy for you guys

```
const AboutUs = (props) => {

 return(
     <section className="about_us_section">
          {textSectionValues}
     </section>
 )
}
```

Through Chrome Developer tools I can see the array created from Object.values being iterated and having the correct values. Unfortunately I haven't managed to render the content to the DOM.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: You're not returning anything from your `valuesText.map`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first, your first loop does not return anything.
second, you need print `item`, because it is the real text.

```
  const textSectionValues = valuesText.map((data) => {
    const values = data[props.language];
    return Object.values(values).map((item) => {
      return (
        <div key={item} className="hero_section_values_container">
          <h3>{item}</h3>
        </div>
      );
    });
  });
```

working example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-currying-n0es7

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure about your data structure? It's array contains only one object which contains the data, so the first map is redundant.
Check this out

```
const valuesText = {
  GB: {
    0: "Responsibility",
    1: "Hospitality",
    2: "Attention to detail",
    3: "Adaptability",
    4: "Efficiency",
    5: "Passion for Quality"
  },
  PT: {
    0: "Responsabilidade",
    1: "Hospitalidade",
    2: "Detalhe e pormenor",
    3: "Adaptabilidade",
    4: "Eficiência",
    5: "Paixão pela Qualidade"
  }
};

export default function App(props) {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {Object.values(valuesText[props.language]).map((value, index) => (
        <h1 key={index}>{value}</h1>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```